# Problemas para fazer uma query livre com codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou aqui hoje para pedir uma auxilio daqueles que são mais experientes do que eu no assunto. Eu tenho uma query livre com codeigniter, que da erro na execução, Mas quando executo ela no Workbenth vai certinho. Vou deixar abaixo o codigo e espero que alguem possa me dar uma ajuda.

```
protected $cms;

// Construção da classe pai
public function __construct(){  
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->cms = $this->load->database('cms', TRUE);
}

// pega os atributos para exibir no carousel
function getCarousel(){

    $this->cms->query('SELECT titulo.post_title, titulo.post_name, anexo.ID, anexo.guid 
                FROM 
                    pt_posts anexo
                inner join pt_posts titulo on titulo.ID = anexo.post_parent
                WHERE 
                    anexo.post_type = "attachment"
                ORDER BY 
                    ID 
                DESC LIMIT 4');     
    $query = $this->cms->get()->result();
    if ($query) {
        return $query;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quando você usa a função `query()` do CodeIgniter não use `get()` logo após, pois `query()` já é uma função por si completa. Obtenha o result set da sua consulta assim, por exemplo:

```
$this->cms->query("
    SELECT
        titulo.post_title,
        titulo.post_name,
        anexo.ID,
        anexo.guid 
    FROM 
        pt_posts anexo INNER JOIN pt_posts ON
            titulo on titulo.ID = anexo.post_parent
    WHERE 
        anexo.post_type = 'attachment'
    ORDER BY 
         ID DESC
    LIMIT 4
");    

$result_set = $query->result_array();

// Imprimindo na tela o result set
print_r($result_set);
die();
```